# how do i rename or assign name to some observations in a column in another column

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to regroup some rows in a dataset
This is my data below

| Status | Count | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ambi | 20 | ₦4,850 |
| Area | 11 | ₦7,150 |
| error1 | 461 | ₦106,909 |
| error2 | 659 | ₦224,723 |
| unuccessful | 1 | ₦100 |
| not executed | 1 | ₦200 |
| Successfu | 43 | ₦4,444 |
| feed | 4 | ₦2,111 |
| Cut | 10 | ₦1,500 |

I want to Create a column and name it status2 then in this status2 will be the regrouping of Status
for example

Anywhere you see ambi and area in Status column, categorize it as Failed in Status2 column

Anywhere you see error1 and error2 in Status column, categorize it as connection error in Status column2

Anywhere you see unsuccessful and not_executed in Status column, categorize it as Failure in Status2 column

and leave the others in the Status column the way they are in the new Status2 column aside the ones i mention to rename their names

here is my code
My R knowledge is limited

```
error>%
      mutate(Status_2 <-ifelse(error$Status %in% c(Ambi,Area,error1,error2,unuccessful,not 
executed),
```

Im lost i dont know if im on the right part with the code

here is how I want the outcome to look like

| Status | Count | Value | Status2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ambi | 20 | ₦4,850 | Failed |
| Area | 11 | ₦7,150 | Failed |
| error1 | 461 | ₦106,909 | Connection error |
| error2 | 659 | ₦224,723 | Connection error |
| unuccessful | 1 | ₦100 | Failure |
| not executed | 1 | ₦200 | Failure |
| Successful | 43 | ₦4,444 | Successful |
| feed | 4 | ₦2,111 | feed |
| Cut | 10 | ₦1,500 | Cut |

**Sample Data**

```
structure(list(Status = c("Ambi", "Area", "error1", "error2", 
"unuccessful", "not_executed", "Successfu", "feed", "Cut"), Count = c(20L, 
11L, 461L, 659L, 1L, 1L, 43L, 4L, 10L), Value = c("<U+20A6>4,850", 
"<U+20A6>7,150", "<U+20A6>106,909", "<U+20A6>224,723", "<U+20A6>100", 
"<U+20A6>200", "<U+20A6>4,444", "<U+20A6>2,111", "<U+20A6>1,500"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use the following solution. There have some typos in your data set that's why some words may appear incorrect. Here we use `case_when`, the LHS must evaluate to a logical vector and the RHS must evaluate to the same type of vector. Here because our `Status_2` vector is of type `character` so should be the RHS of our `case_when` function.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Status_2 = case_when(
    Status %in% c("Ambi", "Area") ~ "Failed",
    Status %in% c("error1", "error2") ~ "connection error",
    Status %in% c("unuccessful", "not_executed") ~ "Failure",
    TRUE ~ Status
  ))

# A tibble: 9 x 4
  Status       Count Value    Status_2        
  <chr>        <int> <chr>    <chr>           
1 Ambi            20 <U+20A6>4,850   Failed          
2 Area            11 <U+20A6>7,150   Failed          
3 error1         461 <U+20A6>106,909 connection error
4 error2         659 <U+20A6>224,723 connection error
5 unuccessful      1 <U+20A6>100     Failure         
6 not_executed     1 <U+20A6>200     Failure         
7 Successfu       43 <U+20A6>4,444   Successfu       
8 feed             4 <U+20A6>2,111   feed            
9 Cut             10 <U+20A6>1,500   Cut
```

In case you would like to use `ifelse`:

```
df %>%
  mutate(Status_2 = ifelse(Status %in% c("Ambi", "Area"), "Failed", 
                           ifelse(Status %in% c("error1", "error2"), "connection error",
                                  ifelse(Status %in% c("unuccessful", "not_executed"), 
                                         "Failure", Status))))
```

Comment: Thanks, Anoushirvan both method works fine

Comment: My pleasure. Wish you the very best of luck.